# Recorrido array múltiples PHP

Tags: php, array, servicio

Hola que tal amigos que tal tengo problemas como recorrer este json no se si es multiple o dimensional, allí vamos estoy consumiendo una web service y me devuelve ese json donde me muestra 2 array principales y dentro de cada array hay mas arrays 1 o mas para recorrer los arrays principales hago un for y para los secundarios hago otro for pero el tema esta en que cuando tiene solo un array dentro del principales no muestra pero en caso de que tenga mas de 1 uno si, no se si estaré haciéndole bien.

En la imagen muestra el json lo correcto debería ser que el asiento 19473575 solo muestre 1 vez y el otro asiento 15120251 esta mostrando correcto los 3 que tengo dentro.

Alguna sugerencia me vendría de mucha ayuda.

[image: imagen]

```
{"listarAsientosResponse":{"asientos":{"transaccion":13978138,"nroTotalPag":4,"listAsientos":[{"idImgAsiento":19473575,"numPag":1,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":{"nroPagRef":4,"pagina":1}},{"idImgAsiento":15120251,"numPag":3,"tipo":"ASIENTO","listPag":[{"nroPagRef":1,"pagina":1},{"nroPagRef":2,"pagina":2},{"nroPagRef":3,"pagina":3}]}]}}}
```

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://ws3.pide.gob.pe/Rest/Sunarp/ListarAsientos?......&out=json",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$ressunartdetalle = json_decode($response, true);
$dato1   = $ressunartdetalle['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listAsientos'];
$logitud1 = count($dato1);
?>
<table>
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $logitud1; $i++) {
        $dato2    = $ressunartdetalle['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listAsientos'][$i]['listPag'];
        $largo2 = count($dato2);
        for ($k = 0; $k < $largo2; $k++) {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td class='text-center'><?php echo $dato1[$i]['idImgAsiento']; ?></td>
                <td class='text-center'><?php echo $dato1[$i]['numPag']; ?></td>
                <td class='text-center'><?php echo $dato1[$i]['tipo'];  ?></td>
                <td class='text-center'><?php echo $dato2[$k]['nroPagRef']; ?></td>
                <td class='text-center'><?php echo $dato2[$k]['pagina']; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno respondiéndome a mi mismo lo solucione nomas me olvide de ponerlo por acá también para si alguien en algún futuro tiene este problemita.

```
//ARRAY Y VER SI ES TIENE 1 O MAS
$datoasiento  = $ressunartdetalle['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listAsientos'];
$logitudasiento = count($datoasiento); // TAMAÑO DEL ARRAY

// SI ES UN ARRAY NO ES NECESARIO EL FOR

//En el primer for es para hacer el recorrido de los array principales
//En el segundo for es para recorrer los arrays secundarios dentro de los principales y también si solo tiene 1 o mas array secundarios

//El isIndexedasientos  lo uso para ver si tiene 1 o mas arrays secundarios.

 for ($i = 0; $i < $logitudasiento; $i++) {
        $nroTotalPagVarios   = $ressunartdetalle['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listAsientos'][$i]['numPag'];
        $valor   = $ressunartdetalle['listarAsientosResponse']['asientos']['listAsientos'][$i]['listPag'];
        $isIndexedasientos = array_values($valor) === $valor;
        for ($k = 0; $k < $nroTotalPagVarios; $k++) {
            if ($isIndexedasientos == null) {
                echo $datoasiento[$i]['idImgAsiento'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['numPag'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['tipo'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['listPag']['nroPagRef'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['listPag']['pagina'] . "<br>";
            } else {
                echo $datoasiento[$i]['idImgAsiento'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['numPag'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['tipo'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['listPag'][$k]['nroPagRef'] . "-" . $datoasiento[$i]['listPag'][$k]['pagina'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

En el primer for es para hacer el recorrido de los array principales.
En el segundo for es para recorrer los arrays secundarios dentro de los principales y también si solo tiene 1 o mas array secundarios.

Bueno muchachos así lo solucione.